# How to move contacts to another group in pidgin/purple/finch via DBus?

Tags: dbus, pidgin, libpurple

I didn't find a way to move multiple contact buddies to another group in pidgin/finch/libpurple over [DBus](https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/DbusHowto#CallingPidginmethods) (e.g. with python) ? I didn't find anything in the [API 1](https://developer.pidgin.im/doxygen/dev2.x.y/html/blist_8h.html)|[2](https://developer.pidgin.im/doxygen/dev2.x.y/html/account_8h.html#details)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kinda confusing but you want to use `purple_blist_add_contact()`.  Unfortunately I can't help you with the Python part, but in C you would:

```
// First get the contact of the buddy
PurpleContact *contact = purple_buddy_get_contact(buddy);
// Find the group. Potentially, create the group if it doesn't exist
PurpleGroup *new_group = purple_blist_find_group("New group name");

purple_blist_add_contact(contact, new_group, NULL);
```

Contacts can only be part of one group so it effectively moves it from one group to another.  Hopefully the C code is enough to know which Python/dbus calls to make.

Comment: Thank you very much, wouldn't have figured out that for myself